# How to give sequential unique id to students in my database?

Tags: sql, database, django-models, design-patterns, erp

I am using Django and Django Rest Framework for the backend of my Student Management System. The database is going to be postgresql. I want to give a unique student number to each student that gets admission(let's call that **STD_ID**). I have searched around and all the answers suggest getting the highest value of the STD_ID column from the database and saving the new record by incrementing the highest value. That works fine but there is a problem.

The issue is let's say the last entered student has the ***STD_ID 100***, now the next one will be ***101*** all good but what happens when I delete the student with ***STD_ID 100***. Now the highest STD_ID will be ***99*** and the next student will be ***100***. It won't create a conflict in the table because it does not remember having ***STD_100*** but in physical records, lets say student reports and all that which were issued to previous ***STD_ID 100*** students will exist and the new student will also be issued reports and such in the same ***STD_ID***.

So I guess you see the issue here. There are now two students with the same ID. One is no longer in the database but he used to be and one day it can cause problems.

What I want to do is have a way to assign ***STD_ID*** without this issue. One way I can think of is having a second table which stores the last student id issued so that the next student is saved with a unique id regardless of whether student has been deleted or not.

But, I am not sure how this system would handle multiple users. Let's say two users try to save a student record at the same time, they will get new unique numbers but for some reason one of the requests to save the record fails and now there is a gap in the ***STD_ID***.

So, how is this handled in the industry because ***STD_ID*** does not seem like a big issue but just assume we are dealing with invoice numbers and a number is skipped in the sequence. Well, that would be a mess to sort out in internal records and auditors will get unnecessary suspicion.
Any guidance will be much appreciated.

PS. I am still learning all this on my own and this is I think my first question on StackOverflow. So, I apologise for any blunders or mistakes, any advice on asking questions and suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: PostgreSQL has features to create columns to be auto-incrementing. If I'm not mistaken, these auto-increment columns only increment and do not decrement, leaving these gaps in the columns. This means, if you create a row and it has ID 100, then delete ID 100, and next time you insert a row, it will have ID 101. Or do you have other requirements for this column?

Comment: Really? I did not know that. I thought it would go back and sometimes create two records with the same id. Yes, postgres has way of auto increment but I cant find the feature in Django Models. They have [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields-1) this method of adding auto increment fields but it overrides the id field and I do not want that.

Comment: @PhilMasteG Nevermind, there is a way to have multiple auto increment columns in Django Models [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield). Thank you for your support.